# finding changes eclipse makes to maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a maven project which I have downloaded [from this link](https://github.com/rajgowda/spring-petcare).  When I make a couple changes to it, it runs perfectly from the command line when I type:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run-war -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

in the directory to which the zip was extracted. (The only 2 changes required to make it work on the command line are to 1.) add a plugin tag for tomcat 7 in pom.xml and 2.) create a context.xml file in the webapp/META-INF folder. Everything else in the app remains the same as the github verion, and the app runs fine from the command line using the command given above and then typing the url in the browser.)

However, when I import the project into eclipse as an existing maven project, and then try to run the app, the app starts throwing errors related to not finding a couple of jars which are clearly in the repository.  The app no longer compiles from the command line, or from eclipse.  I even tried to run the app as a maven build from eclipse and even changed the maven instance eclipse uses to the freestanding maven that works from the command line instead of the embedded maven in eclipse, but the app still threw the same errors when I tried to run it.

But then, when I repeated the steps with a fresh copy of the app, the fresh copy runs fine from the command line, while the copy that eclipse touched does not compile by any method.

It seems that eclipse has made some changes to the app in the process of importing it as an existing maven project into eclipse.  How can I locate the specific changes that eclipse has made to the app?  I would like to be able to use eclipse as my IDE, but I cannot do so unless it can compile the code.

Comment: First set your eclipse to use the JDK instead of the JRE, second (as you already did) change eclipse maven to look at installed maven that runs on the command line again. I've encountered some problems with maven running with the JRE instead of the JDK. Try it and let me know. I will sleep now. Tomorrow I will see what happened.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you very much.  Deleting all the references to JREs in eclipse, then cleaning all the projects and rebuilding the workspace, fixed the problem.  If you want to write your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @CodeMed Glad that it helped. I turn into an answer like you asked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was originally posted as a comment it turns out that resolved the OP's problem, and as He asked I'm turning into an answer.

First set your eclipse to use the JDK instead of the JRE. Just as a reference this configuration on Eclipse is Normally on `Window->Preferences...->Java->Installed JREs:`

Second (as you already did) change eclipse maven to look at installed maven that runs on the command line again.

I've encountered some problems with maven running with the JRE instead of the JDK. Try it and let me know. I will sleep now. Tomorrow I will see what happened.